# JPA-persisting using PK only

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I have a control data DB-TABLE entity

```
@Table(name = "A")
class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "A_OID")
    private Long pk;
}
```

and a DB-VIEW entity referring to the above DB-TABLE and a few others

```
@Table(name = "A_VIEW")
class ARef {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "A_OID")
    private Long pk;

    private String value;
}
```

from which some `value`'s are joined in. The `pk` is referring to the same row. How can I save my entity `B`, referring to `ARef`, using `A`, something like this:

```
class B {
    public ARef a;
}

A a = em.find(A.class, pk);
B b = new B();
b.a = a; // How to do this? Using pk somehow?
```

There is more to it than that, so can't simply do `ARef a = em.find(ARef.class, pk);` instead.

I know there is some type of "native SQL" support in OpenJPA, but that would be too low level.

Comment: JPA doesn't define/allow direct update of entity fields from other classes (only via setters). Obviously some JPA provider may support it (e.g DataNucleus JPA does) but many will not.

Answer (score 0):

First you should change ARef to public if You wanna use "b.a" to instantiate.

```
class B {
    public ARef a;
}

A a = em.find(A.class, pk);
B b = new B();
b.a = a;
```

Backing to the problem..
I use to pass the reference as a parameter from the controller class to view class

Like this:

```
A a = new A();
ARef aref = new ARef(a);
```

Comment: Sorry but that won't cut it (I could have just done a `em.find(ARef.class)`), I need the object to be managed right away, and performance is critical.

Comment: I see.. sorry that I couldn't help. Hope you solved the problem